# How to prove that $ \bar e_2 = e_1 \sin (w) + e_2 \cos(w)$ where $w$ is the angle between $e_1$ and $e_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, angle, orientation

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 201, it is asked that

> Consider an oriented inner product space of dimension 2. Given two
> positive orthonormal bases $e_1, e_2$ and $\bar e_1, \bar e_2$, prove
> that
> $$\begin{align*}\bar e_1 &= e_1 \cos(w) - e_2 \sin(w) \\ \bar e_2 &= e_1 \sin (w) + e_2 \cos(w)\end{align*}$$
> where $w$ is the oriented angle between $e_1$ and $\bar e_1.$
>
> **Note:**  $$\cos(w) = \frac{(e_1, \bar e_1)}{|e_1|\cdot|\bar e_1|},  \quad \sin(w) = \frac{\Delta(e_1, \bar e_1)}{|e_1| \cdot |\bar e_1|}$$ where
> $\Delta$ is the oriented determinant function.

I have proved the first statement easily, but to prove the second, I have argued that the coefficient matrix of this system has to be a orthogonal matrix and proved the second part in that way.

So my question is that how can we prove the second part differently ?

Answer (score 0):

Perform a rotation through the angle $w$ on basis $e_1, e_2$, the result is basis $\bar{e}_1, \bar{e}_2$. The rotation can be represented as a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) as

$$
R = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(w) & -\sin(w) \\  
\sin(w) & \cos(w) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \bar{e}_1 \\ \bar{e}_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
= R \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ e_2 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Yeah, I know that already, but what I do not know is that how to prove it!